# Return Null JSON Response instead of empty response {}

Tags: asp.net-web-api, httpresponsemessage

I have a WEB API that returns null data sometimes.
I am expecting the below format as response

```
{"cardResponse" : null}
```

but I am getting `{}` as response. Any Idea?

My method Definition looks like:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Opeation(string input1, [FromUri] input2 request)
```

The return statement looks like :

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response);
```

Response Class Structure:

```
public class RootResponse    {

    public CardResponse cardResponse{ get; set; }

}

  Public class CardResponse  {

    public string CardName { get ; set;}  
}
```

Comment: Which type is it `response` ?

Comment: Not an ASP expert here, but I'm pretty sure you'll need to post more code. What's the value of `response` in the last snippet? Show the code around that line

Comment: @OrelEraki Edited the Question. Added the response Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `NullValueHandling` option set to `NullValueHandling.Ignore` in your JSON formatter. Check WebApiConfig if there is default formatter replaced or someone could turn-off null values passing for default `JsonMediaTypeFormatter`.

Comment: Wow. Thanks alot :)  Seems I have added that line.